# Credit Cards drawn as Cash Advance to the max and moved abroad altogether

Tags: credit-card, cash, working-abroad, balance

I came to know through one of my friends that one of his colleagues, who lived and worked in US for 6+ years completely relocated to his home country (and no plans to return) and settling there. He has had 3 credit cards with credit line worth 35K combined. He drew all of them as Cash Advance and left US.

How are the CC companies going to pursue this issue? For one, he drew $14.5K from Amex CC. Are they able to pursue this guy abroad?

I guess this is a loophole. If people like these are unaffected after doing this, by moving abroad,  then it opens up huge abuse of system.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of this happening with international students. I would assume they would never be able to return to the US, or at least not be able to use our financial system again. It's theft and there might be other legal consequences as well, given that its in the tens of thousands of dollars.

Comment: Well, this guys has no plans to return to US anymore. He is going to stop working and start his own business in his home country. How is he going to be pursued? Is there a system in place.

Answer (score 0):

Under US law (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ker_v._Illinois) a US court does not take note of how a defendant came to be in US jurisdiction.  AmEX and fellow victims could arrange to kidnap the thief, stick him on a plane/train/taxi to the US, and have him arrested as soon as he entered the US.

Exactly this scenario occurred between Canada and the US.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidnapping_of_Sidney_Jaffe

Comment: Maybe, but the kidnapping could still be illegal in the other country and prosecuted as such.

Comment: I understand this is the case when enters US again. He is never going to enter US again and he is leaving the job as well and start his own local business. So the Employer channel will also not work.